# Select class not working in my webdriver program

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate this dropdown but I am getting the error: 
`Element should have been "select" but was "b"`

The dropdown has lists starting with:

```
<li class="active-result result-selected highlighted" style="" data-option-array-index="0">Select Country</li>
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">United States</li>
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">India</li>
```

And my code is:

```
<Select sel=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='profile_country_chosen']/a/div/b")));
        sel.selectByVisibleText("India");`
```

Please do tell me what am I doing wrong here.
Thanks.

Comment: The xpath (//div[@id='profile_country_chosen']/a/div/b) probably does not resolve to a select element. Can you provide the HTML code of your select box?

Comment: <li class="active-result result-selected highlighted" style="" data-option-array-index="0">Select Country</li> 
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">United States</li> 
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">India</li>

Comment: Those are the list items. Contents of the select box. We need the surrounding HTML tags. Should be something like <div>...</div>.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this code:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.className("active-result"))).selectByVisibleText("India");
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, your xpath expression 
`//div[@id='profile_country_chosen']/a/div/b`
is not a select box but something else. That is why `Select sel` cannot be instanciated. Try to find the correct xpath expression for your `<select>` HTML element.